# Reclass NDVI value using a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, reclassify, function

I'm trying to reclass the values of a sentinel 2 NDVI creating a function but I don't know  exactly  how do to it.
What I exactly want is:
When NDVI values are between -1 and 0, return (-1) ; 
0 and 0.3 return (0); 
0.4 and 1 return (1).

Here's my idea of script:

```
//Imagen Sentinel 2A 
var IMGSentinel2A= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate ('2016-10-01', '2017-03-31')
.filterBounds (geometry)
.filterMetadata ("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",'Less_Than', 5);
var filtropix = ee.Image(IMGSentinel2A.max());
var Sentinel2Clip = filtropix .clip (geometry);

//Bandas
var b4_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B4');
var b8_1 = Sentinel2Clip.select('B8');

// NDVI
var ndvi1 = b8_1.subtract(b4_1).divide((b8_1.add(b4_1)));


var recl = ndvi1.select('B8');
var repl1 = ee.Image(-1);
var repl2 = ee.Image(0);
var repl3 = ee.Image(1);

var zones = function (image) { 
  return image.where(image.gt(-1).and(image.lt(0)), repl1)
  .add(image.where(image.gt(0).and(image.lt(0.3)), repl2))
  .add(image.where(image.gt(0.3)).and(image.lt(1))) };

var output = dndvi.map(zones);

//palette
var bdif_palette = ['00FF00','FF0000'];

Map.addLayer(output,
             {min: 0, max: 2, palette: bdif_palette},
             'reclass NDVI');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the RasterSymbolizer element to display the data either discretely or along a color ramp according to the values such as this for discrete values:

```
 // Define an SLD style of discrete intervals to apply to the image.
var sld_intervals =
  '<RasterSymbolizer>' +
    '<ColorMap  type="intervals" extended="false" >' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="0" label="-1-0"/>' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#00ff00" quantity="0.3" label="0-0.3" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#007f30" quantity="1" label="0.3-1" />' +
    '</ColorMap>' +
  '</RasterSymbolizer>';
```

Or this for a color ramp:

```
// Define an sld style color ramp to apply to the image.
var sld_ramp =
  '<RasterSymbolizer>' +
    '<ColorMap type="ramp" extended="false" >' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="0" label="-1-0"/>' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#00ff00" quantity="0.3" label="0-0.3" />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#007f30" quantity="1" label="0.3-1" />' +
    '</ColorMap>' +
  '</RasterSymbolizer>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you there. Make a series of boolean images based on the breakpoints, sum them and then subtract 2 to adjust the values to your final desired range [-1, 1] (you may need to first mask NDVI values greater than 1 or less than -1, if they happen to exist).

```js
var zones = function(image) { 
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    image.gt(-1),
    image.gt(0),
    image.gt(0.3)])
    .sum()
    .subtract(2);
};
```